# Override Rails controller routing with capital letters in model name

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1

I want to create a model in rails:

```
rails generate model ABCThing
```

So this will create a table, `abc_things`. Great. The problem comes with the controller and routing. I want my controller to be:

```
class ABCThingsController < ApplicationController
end
```

However, after adding in the `routes.rb`

```
resources :abc_things, :only => [:index]
```

and creating the corresponding `index` view, i get the following error in the browser:

```
Expected /app/controllers/abc_things_controller.rb to define AbcThingsController
```

The problem is easy to see (`"ABCThings".tableize.classify => "AbcThing"`), but i'm not so sure how to fix it. I want to override rails default routing from the view to the controller, but am not sure how.

Would appreciate any help (and suggestions for a better question title!)

Comment: Can I ask you why on earth would you want to do that? Conventions are one of RoR strengths, why broke them? BTW model names should not be plural.

Comment: The plural in the model generation was a typo, but surely you can appreciate there are countless three letter acronyms for which capitalizing only the first letter of the acronym really does not make a lot of grammatical sense

Comment: @cthulhu for the same reason Rails supports inflections. They're supposed to be *conventions*, not laws.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

I had this issue and after trying all of the above solutions; was able to fix my problem using the inflector.

In my case the issue was that `TLA::ThingsController` was being resolved as `Tla::ThingsController`

putting the following in my initializers folder fixed it

`config/initializers/inflections.rb`

```
ActiveSupport::Inflector.inflections do |inflect|
  inflect.acronym 'TLA'
end
```

Comment: The default config/inflections.rb file provides this for an example:  `#   inflect.acronym 'RESTful'` which may lead people to infer that the solution to the question as asked is to use `inflect.acronym 'ABCThing'`.  However, my experience is that the line should read `inflect.acronym 'ABC'`.

Comment: @MarkSchneider should make more sense now hopefully with a small adjustment.

Answer (score 3):

You should set custom controller name, in routes.rb:

```
resources :abc_things, :only => [:index], :controller => "ABCThings"
```

Comment: Same error message. I also think you mean `:controller => "ABCThings"`

Comment: oh, sorry, yep only the name without 'Controller' part, edit now

Comment: This will generate a warning now, as per the [Rails Guides](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#specifying-a-controller-to-use): "Only the directory notation is supported. Specifying the controller with ruby constant notation (eg. `:controller => 'Admin::UserPermissions'`) can lead to routing problems and results in a warning."

Comment: Since "Only the directory nottation is supported" now, I accomplished what I wanted this way:
Make a controller at `app/controllers/abc_things_controller.rb` that defines `ABCController` class, then in the routes say: `resources :abc_things, controller: "a_b_c_things"`. Seems to work in Rails 4.2.7

Answer (score 2):

This may have changed with Ruby at some point, but for naming classes with multiple caps in a row (acronyms or initialisms), you no longer need to include the underscore in the file name.

```
# abc_thing.rb
```

could contain

```
class ABCThing

  def hello
    puts "Hello World"
  end

end
```

or

```
class AbcThing

  def hello
    puts "Hello World"
  end

end
```

Answer (score 0):

When you run command

```
rails generate model ABCThings
```

It will generate model and not a controller.
If you want both model and controller use following

```
rails generate scaffold ABCThings
```

I think you are not generate controller by using rails command and hence problem was occured
to generate controller use following command

```
rails generate controller ABCThings
```

and you can `/app/controllers/abc_things_controller.rb` as follows

```
class AbcThingsController < ApplicationController
end
```

Comment: Huh? I created my controller manually. I want to have `class ABCThingsController < ApplicationController` not `class AbcThingsController < ApplicationController`