# Model naming convention for Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, model

[Override Rails controller routing with capital letters in model name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12509176/override-rails-controller-routing-with-capital-letters-in-model-name)

I followed that question and answer, but it did not help me.

I need to create a model from an already existing table, BBOrders.

What is .rb file, class name, how would I access it in the console and do I have to add anything inside the class.

Right now what I have is

```
b_b_order.rb

 class BBOrder < ActiveRecord::Base 
   set_table_name "BBorders"
   set_primary_key "orderID"
end
```

and when I call the BBOrder.all in the console, I get the unitialized constant BBOrder.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
'BBOrder'.underscore #=> 'bb_order'
```

This means your file should be named `bb_order.rb`

Inside of your class you need to change `set_table_name` and `set_primary_key` to the following:

**bb_order.rb**

```
class BBOrder < ActiveRecord::Base 
  self.table_name =  "BBorders"
  self.primary_key =  "orderID"
end
```

Comment: Did all those things. Classify properly returns, but I still don't get the query.

Comment: That fixed that problem, but now when I query it, it says 
BBOrder Load (1.0 ms) EXEC.........
Invalid object name 'bb_orders'
Is that a problem on my part with the DB?

Comment: Side note: I commented out both self.[], but when I brought them back in, I get a different error saying wrong number of arguments (1 for 0).

Comment: I'm not sure, that my be a separate question entirely.

Comment: Josh, just an extra note: the self.[] part was crashing it. I went back to set_table_name and it worked perfectly fine. I read before that set_table_name was deprecated, but not in this case. I am using FreeTDs and TinyTDs, so maybe that's the reason

Comment: I updated my answer which should take care of the wrong number of arguments issue.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/31782/discussion-between-josh-and-alexey)